# I'm trying to save the content of an input into local storage when a button is clicked. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

so I have an input element with the id of "answer" and a button. I've added an event listener for the button and tried to call a function that saves the text inside of the input into local storage. The console is telling me that "innerHTML" is null, but i'm not sure what I'm supposed to do.

```
<input type="text" id="answer" />
<button id="button">click me</button>





var inputAnswer = document.getElementById("#answer")
var buttonEl = document.getElementById("button")

buttonEl.addEventListener("click", saveToStorage())

function saveToStorage() {
localStorage.setItem("task", inputAnswer.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById()` expects an ID, no hashtag. Change `var inputAnswer = document.getElementById("#answer")` to `var inputAnswer = document.getElementById("answer")` (remove the `#`).

`buttonEl.addEventListener("click", saveToStorage())` invokes the `saveToStorage()` function immediately, which is not what you want. Instead, pass it as a reference: `buttonEl.addEventListener("click", saveToStorage)`.

Comment: Remove the ```#``` from  ```var inputAnswer = document.getElementById("#answer")``` also

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="answer" />
<button id="button">click me</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var inputAnswer = document.getElementById("answer");
  var buttonEl = document.getElementById("button");

  buttonEl.addEventListener("click", addAnswerToLocalStorage);

  function addAnswerToLocalStorage() {
    const value = inputAnswer.value;
    localStorage.setItem("answer", value);
  }
</script>
```

There is mistake in getting the reference of input field. Instead of **#answer**  `document.getElementById("#answer")` it should be only **answer** only. Further, I checked it on my local machine and it is working fine.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I got it to work but was just wondering why it's "answer" and not "#answer"? I thought I had to target the id.

Comment: @Ted `getElementById()` expects an ID only, no leading hashtag. The hashtag is used when specifying a CSS selector, e.g. `querySelector('#answer')`.